# How do I handle repetitive / iterative fadeouts of similar class divs in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 6 divs on a page, each has a layer on top that will fadeout on hover, and fade back in on mouseleave. What I have now is this, but the stack overruns if I do it for individual div layers. How do I assign the functionality to all six top layers in a single code block?Thanks for any clues!
[JSFIddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/greenhorncoder/ofzam69y/18/)

```
<script>
    $(function(){      
        $(".hover6").mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).siblings().fadeIn();
            $(this).fadeOut();
        });

        $("#div6").mouseleave(function() {
            $(".hover6").fadeIn('slow');
        });
        $(this).siblings().fadeOut();
    })  
</script>



<script>
    $(function(){      
        $(".hover5").mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).siblings().fadeIn();
            $(this).fadeOut();
        });

        $("#div5").mouseleave(function() {
            $(".hover5").fadeIn('slow');
        });
        $(this).siblings().fadeOut();
    })    
</script>
```

//and so on - identical script for other 4 divs

Comment: Idea, have an attribute called data-number with each div.

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Comment: Assign the same handler to all the divs. The handler will read this attribute and accordingly fade-in/fade-out the appropriate div.

Comment: please provide your HTML.. and maybe you can make a Fiddle..

Comment: Whats the problem with fiddle? and where is relevant code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use common class then you can use class selector to bind events.

*HTML*

```
<div id="div1" class="divContainer">
    <div class='hover hover1'>Overlay on top</div>
    <div>subdiv in div 1</div>
    <div>subdiv in div 1</div>
</div>
```

*Script*

```
//Bind event using common class
$(".hover").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).siblings().fadeIn();
    $(this).fadeOut();
});

$(".divContainer").mouseleave(function () {
    //Use find 
    var hoverElem = $(this).find(".hover");

    hoverElem.fadeIn('slow'); 
    hoverElem.siblings().fadeOut();     
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/z0g26ewq/)

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="wrapper">

  <div id="div1" class="mouse-enter">
   <div>Overlay on top</div>
   <div>subdiv in div 1</div>
   <div>subdiv in div 1</div>

    </div>
   <div id="div2" class="mouse-enter">
     <p class="auto-style1">This is div2</p>
       <div>Overlay on top</div>
       <div>subdiv in div 2</div>
       <div>subdiv in div 2</div>
   </div>
   <div id="div3" class="mouse-enter">
     <div>Overlay on top</div>
     <div>subdiv in div 3</div>
     <div>subdiv in div 3</div>
  </div>
  <div id="div4" class="mouse-enter">
    <div>Overlay on top</div>
    <div>subdiv in div 4</div>
    <div>subdiv in div 4</div>
  </div>
 <div id="div5" class="mouse-enter">
   <div>Overlay on top</div>
   <div>subdiv in div 5</div>
   <div>subdiv in div 5</div>
</div>
<div id="div6" class="mouse-enter">
   <div>Overlay on top</div>
   <div>subdiv in div 6</div>
   <div>subdiv in div 6</div>
</div>
</div>

 $('.mouse-enter').click(
    function(){
    $(this).animate({'width': '100%', 'height':'100%'},600).siblings().animate({'width':'0','height':'0'},600);
    $('<button class="show">XClose</button>')
        .appendTo ('.wrapper');
});

   $(document).on('click','.show', function() {
     $(this).animate({
    'width': '0',
    'height': '0'
  }, 600).siblings().animate({
    'width': '50%',
    'height': '33.33%'
  }, 600);
  $(this).remove();
  });
```

Comment: thanks. I have the click to expand the divs. I'm looking to make the overlay disappear on hover and re-appear on mouseout-without the repetitive code I have currently. I need a separate hover class assigned to the overlay layers.